# Python Encryption Code Is Not Encrypting All Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii

My code is not displaying in Python.  What is wrong?

```
offset_factor = math.floor(number[0]+number[1]+number[2]+number[3]+number[4]+number[5]+number[6]+number[7])
    total = offset_factor
    total = total / 8 - 32
    total = round(total)

    print("This is your offset factor: ")
    print(total)
    string = ''.join(str(e) for e in text_read)
    nospace = string.replace(" ", "")
    print(nospace)

    for b in (nospace):
        string = ""
        ASCII = ord(b)
        result = ASCII + total
        if result > 126:
            result - 96
        else:
            result = result
            result_ascii = chr(result)
            string += result_ascii

    for b in nospace:
        string = ""
        ASCII = ord(b)
        result = ASCII + total
        if result > 126:
            result - 96
        else:
            result = result
            result_ascii = chr(result)
            string += result_ascii
            print(result_ascii)
```

This code is not displaying and I don't know why not, it only encrypts the eight characters but I don't know how to make it encrypt all the characters.

Comment: `result - 96` cannot live as it is, it should be assigned to a name, as in the lines below

Comment: Hmm, what do you expect? I can see no `print` in your code. What should be displayed? (not saying that is `nospace` is empty, the loop does not run)

Comment: Done it, look at my code above

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm trying to run it now... What are the values of `number` and `math` and `text_read`?

Comment: The value of number is number = [] and text_read is the file the user has inputted

Comment: shall I add the full code?

Comment: this is the other code before it 
https://gyazo.com/8058def9428879c4e545e8fd0c0686ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for b in nospace:
    string = ""
    ASCII = ord(b)
    result = ASCII + total
    if result > 126:
        result - 96
    else:
        result = result
        result_ascii = chr(result)
        string += result_ascii
        print(result_ascii)
```

I see a couple of problems here.

- If you want `string` to contain the accumulated values of `result_ascii` at the end of the loop, you shouldn't reset it to the empty string in every iteration. You should only do it once at the beginning.
- If you want `result` to become smaller when it's greater than 126, you have to assign `result - 96` to something.
- If you want `string +=` etc to execute even when the `if` block executes, you shouldn't use an `else` block.
- If you would prefer the output to appear all on one line, don't `print` each character individually.

Try:

```
string = ""
for b in (nospace):
    ASCII = ord(b)
    result = ASCII + total
    if result > 126:
        result = result - 96
    result = result
    result_ascii = chr(result)
    string += result_ascii
print(string)
```

Comment: Might also get rid of the superfluous `result = result` while you're at it... :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not harmful but it is useless.

Comment: Thank you, it encrypts however it encrypts it one by one and displays it way :)

Comment: How do I get it to not do it one by one and display it all in one at once

Comment: By doing `print(string)` instead of `print(result_ascii)`. If you tried that and it didn't work, that's odd because it works on [my machine](http://ideone.com/Lw8PyP).

Comment: Yeah it does work but it displays the code being encrypted one by one I want it to show it when it is finished if I can do that it does it like this, https://gyazo.com/ea1f528d94898d2170481bdb15b20eb9

Comment: It is fine now, just needed to take it out the tab